# Run Sidekiq workers without database connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, scalability, sidekiq

Each Sidekiq worker (thread) requires 1 connection to the database. Postgresql can have at most a few hundreds connections. This is a bottleneck for scalability.

Since I need about 1 thousand workers and Postgresql isn't required (I can pass all the data that I need through Redis and remove the SQL) I am wondering if it's possible to start the Rails environment without connections to Postgresql.

**How can I start Sidekiq workers without Postgresql**?

Note that I still need Postgresql for the normal web app/backend so I cannot remove ActiveRecord altogether from the Rails app.

Comment: Each process does, but not thread. If a thread does not use the connection - it will not take it from pool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a thread doesn't use the database, it won't take a connection.  This assumption is false:

> Each Sidekiq worker (thread) requires 1 connection to the database.

Comment: Directly from the author... Thank you! I thought that a connection was taken from the pool each time a thread was spawn.